# Ajax request does not work if i dont write return false at the end

Tags: ajax

This is my validation function written on button click.

```
 function chk_add_area()
  {
var areaCountry=$('#areaCountry').val();
var areaCity=$('#areaCity').val();
var area=$('#area').val();

if(areaCountry.trim()=="")
{
    $('#err_areaCountry').fadeIn('slow');
    $('#err_areaCountry').html("Please Select Country");
    $('#areaCountry').focus();
    $('#err_areaCountry').fadeOut(3000);
    return false;
}

else //if(areaCountry.trim()!="" && areaCity.trim()!="" && area.trim()!="")
{
    $.ajax({
        url:'ajax.php?action=duplicatearea&areaCountry='+areaCountry+'&areaCity='+areaCity+'&area='+area,
        type:'get',
        success:function(res)
        {
            if(res=="exists")
            {
                $('#err_div').html("Area already exists");
            }
        }

    });
    //return false;
}
/* else
{
    return true;
} */
```

}`

if i uncomment return false,it works properly but then the form does not submit on success & i cant proceed further.
Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: show you HTML as well, suppose you have used `chk_add_area()` function on form submit and when you have add `return false` then form won't submit, if you want to submit form on ajax success call back then add submit form javascript code in ajax success function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `return false` if the area already exists, otherwise drop through.

You don't need to `return true`; just exiting from the function works fine.

```
function chk_add_area() {       // onsubmit handler
var areaCountry = $('#areaCountry').val().trim();
var areaCity = $('#areaCity').val().trim();
var area = $('#area').val().trim();

if ( areaCountry == "" ) {
    $('#err_areaCountry').fadeIn('slow');
    $('#err_areaCountry').html("Please Select Country");
    $('#areaCountry').focus();
    $('#err_areaCountry').fadeOut(3000);
    return false;
}

if ( areaCity == "" || area == "" ) {
    $('#err_div').html("Please Select City and Area");
    return false;
}

$.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php?action=duplicatearea&areaCountry=' + areaCountry + 
            '&areaCity=' + areaCity + '&area=' + area,
        type: 'get',
        async: false,          // EDIT: added Dec 30
        success: function(res) {
            if ( res == "exists" ) {
                $('#err_div').html("Area already exists");
                return false;
            }
        }
// allow form submit to proceed
}
```

Also, I recommend using POST instead of GET because GET is cacheable. Someone might add the same area twice.

Comment: but if i remove return false, ajax request appears in red & form gets submitted before the ajax response is returned.

Comment: I've added "async: false" to the code. That will force the ajax call to wait for a response from the server before it drops through. By default, the ajax call will return right away so that other code can run, while execution of the "success" function is deferred until a response is received from the server.